# Civ 5 crashing when playing with a large number of AIs - crash log enclosed

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-5

I've been playing Civ 5 on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) with the best laptop specs that were available at the time. I have admittedly been playing a pretty insane scenario - Small map with 22 AIs on Emperor. Yes, I know this is ridiculous, but it has been super fun.

Anyway, the game keeps crashing.

- I always play on Strategic View.
- I've minimized graphics settings.
- My computer is fully updated.
- I don't run any programs while I have Civ running.
- I have various official DLCs installed and use the Enhanced User Interface mod.

It crashed first around ~50 turns in, and I haven't been able to play many turns since then without another crash.

I've put the crash log below. Any tips?

Thanks everyone. <3

**Crash log**: http://pastebin.com/mQDTAz2s

Comment: Check the usual stuff: Ram usage, GPU/CPU temperatures. How much ram is just the civ 5 process using when it crashes?

Comment: Have you been able to play against every AI individually without crashing? I had troubles (in linux) with some civilizations from DLCs, the crash happening randomly when such civ reached a specific advancement or tech. Maybe following [this link](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/installing-mods-on-civ5-for-mac.477763/) could help

Answer (score 1):

I have found that all of the Civ5 crashes I've been having was due to one file called CvGameCore_Expansion2.dll located in `Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier's Civilization V/Assets/DLC/Expansion2`

I disabled the file by naming it CvGameCore_Expansion2.dll save.

Of course I can only play Gods & Kings now, but it was well worth the trade off. No more crashes.